# Why doesn't simulation show KM estimators approach the true survival function?

Tags: r, survival, hazard

I'm trying to simulate a survival data with very large sample size and show that the KM estimators approach the true survival function, however it ends up that the two are visually quite different. I think I wasn't comparing the right thing but I couldn't find where I did wrong.

First I simulate a survival data with 100K observations, max follow-up time 50, censoring rate 0.8, and specify the baseline hazard function. I use the Weibull distribution but go for the easy way that lambda=0.02 and rho=1 so that baseline hazard is a constant:

```r
library(coxed)
library(KMsurv)

set.seed(20210330)
nsample=1e5
lambda=0.02
rho=1
true.beta=0.4

myhaz=function(t){
  # lambda*rho*(t^(rho-1))
  0.02
}
simdata <- sim.survdata(N=nsample, T=50, censor=.8, 
                        num.data.frames = 1, beta = 0.4, 
                        hazard.fun=myhaz,
                        X=data.frame("X"=r_sample_binary(nsample, 
                        x = 0:1, prob = c(0.8,0.2), name = "Binary")))
simdata$data$event=as.numeric(simdata$data$failed)
```

If I look at the baseline survival probabilities from the simulated data:

```r
> simdata$baseline$survivor
 [1] 0.9801987 0.9607894 0.9417645 0.9231163 0.9048374 0.8869204 0.8693582 0.8521438 0.8352702 0.8187308
[11] 0.8025188 0.7866279 0.7710516 0.7557837 0.7408182 0.7261490 0.7117703 0.6976763 0.6838614 0.6703200
[21] 0.6570468 0.6440364 0.6312836 0.6187834 0.6065307 0.5945205 0.5827483 0.5712091 0.5598984 0.5488116
[31] 0.5379444 0.5272924 0.5168513 0.5066170 0.4965853 0.4867523 0.4771139 0.4676664 0.4584060 0.4493290
[41] 0.4404317 0.4317105 0.4231621 0.4147829 0.4065697 0.3985190 0.3906278 0.3828929 0.3753111 0.3678794
```

and compare to my true survival probability, which can be calculated from my true baseline hazard:

```r
St=exp(-lambda*(c(1:50)^rho))
> St
 [1] 0.9801987 0.9607894 0.9417645 0.9231163 0.9048374 0.8869204 0.8693582 0.8521438 0.8352702 0.8187308
[11] 0.8025188 0.7866279 0.7710516 0.7557837 0.7408182 0.7261490 0.7117703 0.6976763 0.6838614 0.6703200
[21] 0.6570468 0.6440364 0.6312836 0.6187834 0.6065307 0.5945205 0.5827483 0.5712091 0.5598984 0.5488116
[31] 0.5379444 0.5272924 0.5168513 0.5066170 0.4965853 0.4867523 0.4771139 0.4676664 0.4584060 0.4493290
[41] 0.4404317 0.4317105 0.4231621 0.4147829 0.4065697 0.3985190 0.3906278 0.3828929 0.3753111 0.3678794
```

The two are identical because I have large enough sample size.
However if I calculate the KM estimators, they are quite different from St:

```r
km_fit <- survfit(Surv(y, event) ~ X, data=simdata$data)
km=summary(km_fit, times = c(1:50))$surv[1:50]
> km
 [1] 0.9962515 0.9919738 0.9882571 0.9844797 0.9806792 0.9772240 0.9730233 0.9694796 0.9654927 0.9618635
[11] 0.9578942 0.9544436 0.9505571 0.9467933 0.9431748 0.9395630 0.9361808 0.9324463 0.9291364 0.9256540
[21] 0.9217372 0.9181445 0.9147239 0.9108842 0.9078288 0.9048339 0.9014076 0.8976344 0.8943120 0.8910748
[31] 0.8879073 0.8843805 0.8806476 0.8772176 0.8740362 0.8708713 0.8671436 0.8635299 0.8604316 0.8565315
[41] 0.8529732 0.8495042 0.8459996 0.8426619 0.8391398 0.8359729 0.8327033 0.8292976 0.8264344 0.0000000
```

Here's also a plot comparing the two:

[Survival plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NwiA.png)

Why are the two so different?

Comment: What are you putting in for the argument `event`  to the `Surv` function when you haven't simulated any censoring process? Also on what value of `X` are you conditioning for the output of `survfit`? One may be using prediction at the means, while the other sets `X` to 0.

Comment: If you do `with (simdata$data,table(event, y==50))` you will see that all the times that reach 50 (ie, censored) have `event==1`, which suggests there's an issue with the coding  of the event indicator.

Answer (score 4):

I am reasonably sure there's a problem with the simulation software.  The documentation says

> if `censor.cond` is `FALSE` then a proportion of the observations
> specified by censor is randomly and uniformly selected to be
> right-censored

That matches the code, which has

```
            ifelse(censor.cond, data$failed <- !censor.x(xdata, 
                censor = censor), data$failed <- !(runif(N) < 
                censor))
```

But that isn't what censoring should do. That sets the censoring indicator independent of the survival time, when actually it's the censoring hazard that should be independent of the survival time.  Setting the censoring indicator independent of the survival time implies a lower censoring rate for long survival times and a higher one for short survival times.

On top of that, the censoring indicator appears to be coded the opposite way to how I would expect and how you used it

With `censor=0.8`

```
> with(simdata$data, table(event, y==50))
     
event FALSE  TRUE
    0 52629     0
    1 12818 34553
```

With `censor=0.99`

```
>  with(simdata$data, table(event, y==50))
     
event FALSE  TRUE
    0 64798     0
    1   649 34553
```

And if you look at the results of `survfit` as the `censor` parameter is increased, the fitted survival probabilities get higher and higher -- and further and further from your known baseline curve.  That's what would happen with the documented censoring behaviour, but it's not what you'd usually want. The published paper about the method ([Harden & Kropko](https://doi.org/10.1017/psrm.2018.19)) doesn't give much information about how censoring would be generated; it goes into detail on the survival time generation.

The code quoted above also makes me nervous. I looked up the R documentation and I think it's correct, since `censor.cond` is a single value and is always either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, so exactly one of the two assignments will be evaluated and the rules for lazy evaluation mean it will be evaluated in the calling frame of the `ifelse()` function rather than inside the function. But I think the authors wanted `if` rather than `ifelse`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Thomas, what you wrote makes a lot of senses to me. I actually did simulation again using my own written function, and the KM curve and true survival probability curve are quite consistent with each other. I'm going to write to the author reporting this issue. I'll post updates here if any.
However I just don't get the part "the censoring indicator appears to be coded the opposite way" - I think it's alright as the failed variable is the failure indicator which is opposite to the censoring indicator. Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the question and feedback. We are in the process of making some changes to address these issues. See the Github page for updates: https://github.com/jkropko/coxed.

On the censoring problem, we followed some previously published papers' simulations with that decision primarily because it was simple and censoring was not the main focus of our work. But we agree with Prof. Lumley that we need to generate a censoring hazard independent of survival time. We are working on that.

Thanks again!